# Program to generate a regular expression from a transition table

Tags: finite-automata, automata

Im curious if anyone knows how to write a program to generate a regular expression given a finite automation or if any programs (preferably in c) already exist.

To make things less complicated I want to limit the number of states to about 4, assume the FA is in minimal form and that the FA has only one FinalState and only one StartState.

Ive been thinking about it for a while now and I think the first obvious thing to do would be to create a transition table for the FA.

So an FA could look like this:

```
NumberOfStates 4 
StartState   1 
FinalState   4 
StateNumber  NextStateA   NextStateB
1            2            4
2            3            2
3            4            4
```

This would generate the regular expression: b + (ab*a(a + b))

Ive been racking my brain for hours but am stumped on how to go about this. Any ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Crossposted and closed on cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4987) where we figured that [another question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016) contained all the answers. Turns out it's code that's needed, so here we are.

Answer (score 3):

Follwoing is the code for implementing FA for (a+b+c)*abc. But I couldn't understand the logic.

```
int main()
{
     char str[50],input[15],inpstate[15],outstate[15],state='A';
     int i=0,j;
     strcpy(input,"abcabcabcabc");
     strcpy(inpstate,"AAABBBCCCDDD");
     strcpy(outstate,"BAABCABADBAA");
     printf("\nEnter the string:-  ");
     gets(str);
     while(str[i]!='\0')
     {
          for(j=0;j<12;j++){
         if(inpstate[j]==state && input[j]==str[i]){
              state=outstate[j];
              break;
          }
           }
          if(j==12){
          state='E';
          break;
        }
        i++;
     }
     if(state=='D')
          printf("\nValid String \n");
     else
          printf("\nInvalid String \n"); 
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YoU can do this with Kleene's algorithm (which is a special case of the Floyd–Warshall algorithm).

You find this implemented, e.g., in the libAMoRE library: http://libalf.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/index.php?page=download